# AWS RDS must use vpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, vpc

When I am trying to launch a RDS DB instance, it seems like I must use a VPC -- there is no choice other than a VPC when I reach Configure Advanced Settings. Is there any way to avoid this?

To motivate this question, I am having problems connecting to the instance once it is created and previously (using a different AWS account) this connection was not a problem.

Could it be that with VPCs configured, then I am forced to choose among them?

Is it surprising that connecting to an RDS instance is more difficult when it runs in a VPC?

Comment: In reading further, I think the following is true: New AWS accounts require all EC2 instances to run within a VPN. This would include RDS instances. So I think, but am not sure, that the answer to my question is: Yes, AWS RDS must use VPC.

Comment: You can connect two VPC with VPC Peering allowing them to access each others private IP space. Note that the CIDR ranges of the two VPC cannot conflict when you do this. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html This is assuming that you don't want to open your RDS instances to public IPs which I wouldn't recommend :)